# Why is a strongly continuous one-parameter semigroup called a $C_0$-semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is [a strongly continuous one-parameter semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_semigroup) called a $C_0$-semigroup? Isn't $C_0$ the set of continuous functions that vanish at infinity?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: continuous at zero semigroup.
A.NIKNAM Ferdowsi university of Mashhad,Iran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of semigroups of operators, $C_0$ or $(C,0)$ abbreviates *[Cesàro summable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesaro_summation) of order zero*.

This simply means the continuity property $\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} T_t x = x$ for all $x \in X$ (convergence in norm) and has nothing to do with continuous functions of compact support or vanishing at infinity.

The notation is explained and discussed in detail in the classic treatise on semigroups:
Hille and Phillips, *[Functional analysis and semi-groups](http://books.google.com/books/about/Functional_Analysis_and_Semi_Groups.html?id=xn-EQyIpYegC&redir_esc=y)*. They impose this and other (weaker) conditions on semi-groups such as $C_1$, *Cesàro summability of order one*, meaning that $x = \lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^t T_s x\,ds$, or variants of [Abel summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_summation).

See [Section 10.6, p.320f](http://books.google.com/books?id=xn-EQyIpYegC&pg=PA320) for a discussion of these and various other classes of semigroups.